# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 33: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, installation

I've been having problems installing matplotlib toolkit for my python. 
After giving the command **pip install basemap-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl**
to my windows command promt, the install begins shortly and runs for a while, but after that, it stops and just gives me the following message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 33: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\lasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 33: invalid continuation byte.
```

I tried to look for answer, but everything I could find had nothing to do with installing, but with code that was written by the user itself, so I got no clue how to apply that information to my case.

Comment: Why can&#39;t you just do `pip install matplotlib` ?? Basically this will install any dependencies.

Comment: That worked out, thanks! I thought the whole .whl package was the matplotlib, hence thats what I got when I downloaded matplotlib. Didn't know that you can just install certain pieces of it.

Comment: I have added the same in answer. If it helped please consider tick mark or upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `pip install matplotlib`

You are installing specific version of a dependency of matplotlib. But the above command will automatically install any dependency of supported version. Which will be specific to your python version.